# tkinter layout 1 pixel out why?

Tags: tkinter

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOfJE.png)

Hi hope you can help.

I can't see why my code produces labels and entry boxes in a frame with a one pixel gap in some places? It shouldn't have a gap at all?

Code:

defines the frame element:

```
def create_frame(self):
    self.frame = Frame(self.root)
    self.frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor="w")
```

1st data entry function:

```
def data_entry_01(self, frame):

    L1 = Label(frame, text="STATE 01", anchor="w", width=23, bg=white)
    L1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    L2 = Label(frame, text="Dry bulb:", anchor="w", width=10, bg=white)
    L2.grid(row=1, column=0)

    E1 = Entry(frame, width=8, state=NORMAL)
    E1.grid(row=1, column=1)

    L3 = Label(frame, text="°C", anchor="w", width=5, bg=white)
    L3.grid(row=1, column=2)

    L5 = Label(frame, text="Humidity:", anchor="w", width=10, bg=white)
    L5.grid(row=2, column=0)

    E2 = Entry(frame, width=8, state=NORMAL)
    E2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    L6 = Label(frame, text="%", anchor="w", width=5, bg=white)
    L6.grid(row=2, column=2)
```

2nd data entry function:

```
def data_entry_02(self, frame):

    L1 = Label(frame, text="STATE 02", anchor="w", width=23, bg=white)
    L1.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=3)

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------

    L2 = Label(frame, text="Dry bulb:", anchor="w", width=10, bg=white)
    L2.grid(row=1, column=3)

    E1 = Entry(frame, width=8, state=NORMAL)
    E1.grid(row=1, column=4)

    L3 = Label(frame, text="°C", anchor="w", width=5, bg=white)
    L3.grid(row=1, column=5)

    L5 = Label(frame, text="Humidity:", anchor="w", width=10, bg=white)
    L5.grid(row=2, column=3)

    E2 = Entry(frame, width=8, state=NORMAL)
    E2.grid(row=2, column=4)

    L6 = Label(frame, text="%", anchor="w", width=5, bg=white)
    L6.grid(row=2, column=5)
```

All row widths add up to 23 so why is there a gap showing?

Comment: You have `anchor="w"` on your Labels and not Entries, could this be the cause?

Comment: I can't anchor an Entry widget, I get an error? "_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-anchor". Do you know how to anchor a Entry widget?

Comment: I have removed the anchor option from all widgets and its still producing the same problem :/

Comment: Since you are using `grid`, you could add the option `sticky=E+W` on each item to expand the items to fill the 'space' in the grid. If there is a still a gap vertically, you can use `sticky=N+E+S+W.

Comment: Bob on! super star, thanks mate :)

Comment: No problem, could you mark the answer I just made as correct? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to fill in the 'space' around each item using the `grid` geometry manager, you can use the `sticky` argument.

In this case, you can add `sticky=N+E+S+W` in the options for each item, to let them fill the entirety of each space in the grid. This will remove the gap you can see around each item.